# Eliminar elementos repetidos de una lista

Tags: haskell

Estoy tratando de hacer una función en haskell, donde le entre por parámetro una lista y retorne o muestre la lista pero que se eliminen los duplicados es decir:

Ingrese `[1,2,3,4,1,2]` y muestre `[1,2,3,4]`. También puede ser con caracteres no necesariamente con números.

Algo asi:

```
deleteDuplicate :: [a] -> [a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El módulo `Data.List` de Haskell ya cuenta con una función, `nub`, que elimina elementos repetidos de una lista en tiempo `O(n^2)`.

Una forma sencilla de definir esta función es tomar la cabeza `x` de la lista `(x:xs)`, eliminar las ocurrencias de `x` en la cola `xs` (filtrando los elementos distintos de `x` mediante la función `filter`) y eliminar recursivamente los elementos repetidos.

```
deleteDuplicate :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicate [] = []
deleteDuplicate (x:xs) = x : deleteDuplicate (filter (/= x) xs)
```